# Program errors when run from Task Scheduler, but completes when run manually

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a console application that runs twice a day from a job in Task Scheduler.

The application connects to three different databases and does some housework (reconciling different tables).

Upon completion the job sends me an email informing me of either SUCCESS or FAILURE.  Until a couple of days ago the application ran successfully.  However, a couple of days ago I began receiving FAILURE messages.

The message is (condensed for readability):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found
at MyProg.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\BuildAgent6\work\b8eceaf26d023592\MyProg\MyProg\Program.cs:line 29
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
```

However, if I run the application manually (locating the exe in the file system and double-clicking) everything runs correctly to completion.

I have determined that the connection strings for database connection are correct.

I have determined that the account under which the job runs has the correct permissions (if it did not, then the application wouldn't even get to the stage where it was attempting the database connection).  In fact, the line in Program.cs where the application barfs is the **second** database connection; the first connection has already succeeded.  There is nothing I can see about the Login or User on this particular database that would cause the error (and, if there were, why would it succeed when invoked manually?)

So I guess the bottom line is:  why would a program called from a Task Scheduler fail to connect to a database using connection strings stored in App.Config, but succeed when called manually?

Comment: Please check your login credentials and authorization on DB . You must have access on accessing the DB

Comment: Which login credentials have I not checked?  As the message states, "I have determined that the connection strings for database connection are correct." and "I have determined that the account under which the job runs has the correct permissions".

Comment: `he network path was not found` would indicate the host name for the database could not be found (or the SQL Server instance name wasn't found).

Comment: Check your connection string , seems Network address name  not found

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ScheduledJob;Password=MyPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: try to give your job as admin permission

Comment: If the problem were actually that the host name for the database could not be found, why would the program run correctly when invoked manually but fail when invoked by the scheduled task?  It doesn't make any sense ....

Comment: Please confirm if your exe and database resides on same machine? Also, under what credentials your Task Scheduler is running the application?

Comment: If it is running manually then it should be related to permission to that job only. Please try that account as admin and give permission on db side as DB owner

Comment: exe is on one machine, databases are on a different machine.  The task scheduler is running the application with elevated privileges, but the actual program connects to the databases using stored connection strings, and so the account under which the task runs seems to me to be irrelevant (if that account had insufficient privileges it wouldn't be invoked at all - I know it's invoked because I get an email from within the program)

Comment: I've just tested running the task manually (going into Task Scheduler, selecting the Task and clicking "Run") and it works correctly!  Which is slightly/very weird.  The job is due to execute again in an hour under the schedule, so I'll post back if it fails again ....  Thank you everyone so far for your suggestions!

Comment: The scheduled job has now run successfully.  I made no changes either to the source code nor to any of the properties of the task, nor task scheduler, nor the account under which the task runs.  Which is the kind of thing that does my nut in (BrE expression meaning "moderately enrages me".)  So thanks again, everyone.